# Выбор между причастием и деепричастием

Tags: причастия, деепричастия

Есть такой текст:

«Но наши мальчишки не знали эти слова. Они защищали Родину, сестёр, братьев, матерей. Ушедшие в небеса, лежащие в сырой земле, не дожившие, и не зная любви, мальчики и девочки, стоящие на ящиках у станка, кующие силу для Родины».

Подскажите, всё ли грамотно в использовании «не зная любви»? Деепричастие здесь к месту? Или стоит сделать из него причастие, чтобы получились однородные причастия?

Comment: Дарья, у вас ведь сначала было «не долюбившие», — можно узнать, с чего такая правка? Первый вариант был лучше: кто-то из мальчишек («не долюбившие/недолюбившие») успел полюбить до того как уйти на войну и там погибнуть, и его любовь закончилась ничем, кто-то («не знавшие любви») и этого не успел, — здесь была дополнительная мысль. А «не дожившие» абсолютно ничего нового к сказанному не прибавляет.

Answer (score 1):

Причастие (***не знавшие** любви*) употребить не «стоит», а **необходимо:** в противном случае фраза получается косноязычной. Кстати, запятая перед союзом  ***и*** здесь не нужна.

Я бы также посоветовал использовать в первом предложении родительный падеж: *не знали **этих слов***.

Answer (score 1):

**Редактирование** (в качестве варианта)

*Но наши мальчишки не знали этих слов – они защищали Родину, сестёр, братьев, матерей. Они, ушедшие теперь в небеса, лежащие в сырой земле, не дожившие и не узнавшие радости любви.  Мальчики и девочки, стоящие на ящиках у станка и  кующие силу для Родины.*

**Примечание**. Возраст юных защитников Родины был разный. Кому-то довелось попасть на фронт, а кто-то работал на заводах.

Answer (score 0):

"Не зная любви" - здесь невозможно в принципе. У вас в этом предложении глагола вообще нет. О каком деепричастии может идти речь?

Ваш текст надо переделывать кардинально.
И давайте что-нибудь одно. Или "ушедшие в небеса" - или "стоящие на ящиках". Вместе оно как-то издевательски получается.